# displacement maps being applied in the viewport when in solid mode

Tags: 3d-view, displacement

I was recently working on a landscape and animating a robot dog to walk over that landscape. I quickly worked out that I have to have it in rendered mode for it to show the displacement, which meant that I could not animate it in solid mode, as the floor wouldn't line up, so therefore I had to have it in rendered mode. Although in rendered mode it is so unresponsive its unusable. My question is: Is there a way to apply the displacement texture when in solid/material preview?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Unusual workflow... would it be possible/acceptable to use a preview-only   _Displacement_ 
 modifier with the same texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobinBetts said, here in more detail: If you use the same texture from the material's *Displacement Node* as texture in a *Displacement Modifier* with the same settings only visible in the *3D Viewport*, you can use this to work in *Solid View*. The problem here is, the more detailed you want it in *Solid View*, the less responsive it gets as well - but maybe better than in *Rendered View*.

In the following example I have a landscape texture plugged into a *Displacement Node*, with *Strength* > 1.2 and *Midlevel* > 0.0, using the UV map as *Texture Coordinate*.

Setting the *Displacement Modifier* to be disabled in render and *Coordinates* > *UV*, *Strength* > 1.2, *Midlevel* > 0.0 with the same landscape map, the resulting landscape is the same in viewport and render. Of course the plane has to be subdivided enough to give a proper display f the texture. My plane is subdivided, but you can do with a *Subdivision Surface Modifier*  set to *Simple* and also disabled in render.

[image: disp_setup]

Here is the *3D Viewport* render in *Solid View* from the modifier:

[image: disp_viewport]

And this is the real render with the material displacement:

[image: disp_render]